# addPriceBlockType in Ajax Call Magento

Tags: ajax, magento

I use some Plugin from FireGento that override price.html to show additional information like tax and delivery time below my magento price (german specific).

In some layout.xml the plugin define where the new price.html is output.

Example:

```
<!--
Adding custom product price block
-->
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="product_list">
        <action method="addPriceBlockType">
            <type>simple</type>
            <block>magesetup/catalog_product_price</block>
            <template>catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

Everything works fine, but when I work with Ajax Calls my price is show without the additional information.

It is possible to update my layout.xml for ajax calls or it is achievable to set addPriceBlockType when I get my product collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a observer that add the special phtml code from FireGento when my price block is not a instance from FireGento_MageSetup_Block_Catalog_Product_Price

```
public function addPriceGerman(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

        //lese jeden Block aus
        $block = $observer->getBlock();

        //ist der Block ein Price Block aber kein FireGento_MageSetup Preisblock?
        if ($block instanceof Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price AND !$block instanceof FireGento_MageSetup_Block_Catalog_Product_Price) {

            $transport = $observer->getTransport();
            //hole den eigentlichen HTML Code vom Preisblock
            $output = $transport->getHtml();

            //hole das Produkt
            $product = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock()->getProduct();

            //Instanz vom MageSetup Block erzeugen
            $productPrice = new FireGento_MageSetup_Block_Catalog_Product_Price();
            //setze das Produkt
            $productPrice->setProduct($product);

            //Rendern der deutschen Preisinfo
            $germanTemplate = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')
                ->setTemplate('magesetup/price_info.phtml')
                ->setProduct($product)
                ->setFormattedTaxRate($productPrice->getFormattedTaxRate())
                ->setIsIncludingTax($productPrice->isIncludingTax())
                ->setIsIncludingShippingCosts($productPrice->isIncludingShippingCosts())
                ->setPriceDisplayType(Mage::helper('tax')->getPriceDisplayType())
                ->setIsShowShippingLink($productPrice->isShowShippingLink())
                ->setIsShowWeightInfo($productPrice->getIsShowWeightInfo())
                ->setFormattedWeight($productPrice->getFormattedWeight())
                ->toHtml();

            //deutsche preisinfo an ursprünglichen html code anhägen
            $transport->setHtml($output . $germanTemplate);

        }
        return $this;

    }
```